# To set padding for textblock inside ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Border x:Name="Border"  Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DarkGray}" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0">

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header"
                                             TextElement.FontSize="14"  TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"                                            
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                             SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    </ContentPresenter>

                </Border>
```

in the above code there will be a default textblock inside ContentPresenter tag. I need to set padding for that Textblock.

> TextBlock.Padding="8"

will  not work. How to set padding for that TextBlock.

Comment: Set Margin="8" for ContentPresenter

Comment: Set the Padding property directly on the default TextBlock element?

Comment: Margin needs to be added for contentPresenter